# Case insensitive filter in MS Access by VBA code

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, case-sensitive

I have an MS Access front end connected via ODBC to a MySQL database.
I created a short VBA code to apply a filter on a continuous form based on a user's input. (ie. user can search for any part of a name on the list typing some letters and apply the filter by "Enter".)

I would like to make the process to be case insensitive but I can't.

My code is:

```
Option Compare Text    
Private Sub txbNameSearch_AfterUpdate()
 Me.Filter = "GuestName LIKE """ & "*" & TempVars!tvGuestName & "*" & """"
 Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

I thought that "Option Compare Text" should do the trick but it doesn't.
How can I make the filtering to be case insensitive?

Comment: What collation do you use in your table and connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it all to [UCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53e2ew8a(v=vs.90).aspx) to do this.

```
Me.Filter = "UCase([GuestName]) LIKE """ & "*" & UCase(TempVars!tvGuestName) & "*""""
```

Comment: (without the "[" and "]")